# Sql query - Order by number of true values in the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like  this

[image]

I need to get the validity order by the number of true values in the last 4 columns.
For e.g. the output of the below query should be

```
1110  // 4 true values
1001  // 2 true values
1000 // 1 true value
```

Comment: If validity always is 4 char, why not just ``order by validity desc``

Comment: It's not always 4 characters. I simplified the example. It just needs to be sorted by the number of vehicle types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the boolean values to integers and order descending by their total:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY taxi::int + car::int + truck::int + bike::int DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ypzRcdbW).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT 
id,
validity,
taxi1 + car1 + truck1 + bike1
FROM 
(
SELECT
id,
validity
CASE WHEN taxi = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END taxi1,
CASE WHEN car = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END car1,
CASE WHEN truck = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END truck1,
CASE WHEN bike = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END bike1
FROM table
)
```

Comment: Does it order by validity or outputs the number of true boolean values?

Comment: you can add a select case to concat your string to the number

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery;

```
SELECT subquery.VALIDITY,
concat(CAST ((subquery.TAXI + subquery.CAR + subquery.TRUCK + subquery.BIKE) AS TEXT) , ' True values') as COUNTTRUEVALUES
FROM (select VALIDITY,
CASE WHEN TAXI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TAXI,
CASE WHEN CAR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CAR,
CASE WHEN TRUCK THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TRUCK,
CASE WHEN BIKE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIKE
FROM YourTableName) as subquery
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

output

```
VALIDITY COUNTTRUEVALUES

1110      4 True values
1001      2 True values
1000      1 True values
```